# getting"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character" error while make ajax call from user control page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, jquery

i use first time ajax call from asax page.

it is working fine i am getting data in C# page and but when trying get success function than i am getting error msg  in error function

"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character"

here is my code

```
var options = {
         type: "POST",
         url: "ChemistrieAddToCart.aspx",
         data: data,
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         async: false,
         success: function () {                 
             alert("sucsess");
         },
         error: function (xhr, status, error) {
             alert("failed" + xhr.responseText);
             alert(error);
             alert(status);

         }
     };
     var returntext = $.ajax(options).responseText;
     if (returntext = "added") {
         alert("Matched");
        window.location="shoppingcart.aspx"
     }
     else {
         alert("not completed");
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is data ? show the string

Comment: <img src="https://1-800-optisource.com/Email/image/jsonstring.jpg" width="497" height="394"/>

Answer (score 0):

if you are passing `<img src="1-800-optisource.com/Email/image/jsonstring.jpg"; width="497" height="394"/>` as Json string that its is wrong you might look at json format first than pass the value might give you idea and resolve your issue

check json over here : http://www.json.org/